# python 3 import is importing too much

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, import

Import statement for multiple python scripts is not working as expected

I'm setting up a program to inventory the whole bestiary from a game into a python script. The problem here is, it's already printing the last file in line, which it shouldn't do. "bestiary.py" is asking which category you want to open and in it, it should ask you which beast you specifically want from this category. But it's already printing out the whole beast i have even before giving the input that should be necessary.

Here's my github repo for it: https://github.com/Fuutralala/witcher-bestiary-py

i don't actually know which part of the code is actually broken and i can't figure it out. Something seems to be wrong with the way i'm importing but i can't find out what.

Also if i give the script the prompted input it gives me this error:

```
  File "bestiary.py", line 1, in <module>
    import draconids
  File "/home/fuutralala/Dropbox/PythonTrainingRepo/bestiary/draconids.py", line 13, in <module>
    Draconids()
  File "/home/fuutralala/Dropbox/PythonTrainingRepo/bestiary/draconids.py", line 10, in Draconids
    Cockatrice()
NameError: name 'Cockatrice' is not defined
```

Comment: Where did you define or import `Cockatrice`?  A file should do all the imports that particular file requires.

Comment: defined ```Cockatrice``` in a seperate file called cockatrice.py as function called ```Cockatrice():```

Comment: Did you import that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```py
# bestiary.py
from draconids import Draconids


def list():
    print("""
    - Beasts
    - Cursed Ones
    - Draconids
    - Elementa
    - Hybrids
    - Insectoids
    - Necrophages
    - Ogroids
    - Relicts
    - Specters
    - Vampires
    """)

def Bestiary():
    print("""
    Welcome to the Bestiary, where all the evil, malicious and
    devious Creatures are listed.
    Which category of monsters would you like to explore?
    """)
    list()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Bestiary()
    val = input("> ")
    if val == "Draconids" or "draconids":
        Draconids()
    else:
        print("not ready yet")
```

```py
# draconids.py
from cockatrice import Cockatrice


def Draconids():
    print("""
    About which Draconid would you like to learn more?
    - Basilisk
    - Cockatrice
    """)
    val = input("> ")
    if val == "Cockatrice" or "cockatrice":
        Cockatrice()
    else:
        print("not ready yet")
```

```py
# cockatrice.py
def Cockatrice():
        print("""
        Cockatrice, also known as a skoffin and kurolishek, is an ornithosaur.
        It's also the only creature to belong to the order of ornithoreptile
        according to scholars, but why exactly they decided on this is not revealed.
        Its central tail feathers are also valuable as they're more durable and
        sharpen better than regular goose feathers for quills.
        """)
```

Comment: so all i had to do was to NOT run the function by calling it at the end ... pretty simple, thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the problem is with importing. Instead of calling simply `Cockatrice()` you need to call `cockatrice.Cockatrice()`.
Alternatively you can do `from cockatrice import Cockatrice`.